# If else code execution with Optional class

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I was going through a tutorial of Optional class here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-optional-class/ which has the following

```
String[] words = new String[10];
Optional<String> checkNull = Optional.ofNullable(words[5]);
if (checkNull.isPresent()) {
    String word = words[5].toLowerCase();
    System.out.print(word);
} else{
    System.out.println("word is null");
}
```

I am trying to make it of less lines using `ifPresent` check of `Optional` as

```
Optional.ofNullable(words[5]).ifPresent(a -> System.out.println(a.toLowerCase()))
```

but not able to get the else part further

````
Optional.ofNullable(words[5]).ifPresent(a -> System.out.println(a.toLowerCase())).orElse();// doesn't work```
````

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: closet you'll come for java-8 would be `System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(words[5]).map(String::toLowerCase).orElse("Not Present"));`

Comment: *Note*: I've tagged the question with Java-8 based on the link shared by you, feel free to discard or modify the edit.

Comment: have you tried java 9?? BTW good Question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Java-9

Java-9 introduced [`ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)) for something similar in implementation. You could use it as :

```
Optional.ofNullable(words[5])
        .map(String::toLowerCase) // mapped here itself
        .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println,
                () -> System.out.println("word is null"));
```

#### Java-8

With Java-8, you shall include an intermediate `Optional`/`String` and use as :

```
Optional<String> optional = Optional.ofNullable(words[5])
                                    .map(String::toLowerCase);
System.out.println(optional.isPresent() ? optional.get() : "word is null");
```

which can also be written as :

```
String value = Optional.ofNullable(words[5])
                       .map(String::toLowerCase)
                       .orElse("word is null");
System.out.println(value);
```

or if you don't want to store the value in a variable at all, use:

```
System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(words[5])
                           .map(String::toLowerCase)
                           .orElse("word is null"));
```

Answer (score 4):

For a bit to be more clear `ifPresent` will take `Consumer` as argument and return type is `void`, so you cannot perform any nested actions on this

```
public void ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer)
```

> If a value is present, invoke the specified consumer with the value, otherwise do nothing.

**Parameters:**

> consumer - block to be executed if a value is present

**Throws:**

> NullPointerException - if value is present and consumer is null

So instead of `ifPreset()` use `map()`

```
String result =Optional.ofNullable(words[5]).map(String::toLowerCase).orElse(null);
```

**print** Just to print

```
System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(words[5]).map(String::toLowerCase).orElse(null));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **java 9**, you can use `ifPresentOrElse()` method::

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-

```
Optional.of(words[5]).ifPresentOrElse(
   value -> System.out.println(a.toLowerCase()),
   () -> System.out.println(null)
);
```

If **Java 8** then look this **great cheat sheet** :

http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/08/optional-in-java-8-cheat-sheet.html